# How can I show that this infinite product is nonzero?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, infinite-product

How would you show that $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos( 2 \pi/3^k)$ is nonzero?
Wolfram approximates it as about $-0.37$, and I have a guess that 
$$
\Big \vert \prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos( 2 \pi/3^k) \Big \vert\geq c \prod_{k=1}^\infty 3^{-1/k^2},
$$
although I cannot show it.

This product arises as the modulus of the characteristic function of the Cantor distribution.

Comment: When does $cos(x)$ vanish? Does $2\pi/3^k$ achieve some of those values?

Comment: @Dog_69 That is not sufficient. Think of $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-1/(2k))$

Comment: @ClementC. That's true. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\approx 0$, we have $\cos x\approx 1-\frac 12x^2$ and $\ln\cos x\approx-\frac 12x^2 $. This allows you to compare $\sum\ln\cos(2\pi/3^k) $ with a nicely convergent series

Answer (score 3):

It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) that an infinite product of positive terms
$$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-a_n) \ \text{where}\ 0 \le a_n < 1$$
converges (to a nonzero limit) if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$.
In this case
$$a_k = 1 - \cos(2\pi/3^k) \sim \frac{(2\pi/ 3^{k})^2}{2}$$

Comment: Or more precisely, $1-\cos(2π/3^k)=2\sin^2(π/3^k)\le 2\min(1,π/3^k)^2$.

Comment: @LutzL That's not more precise, it's a different argument. Robert Israel's asymptotic argument *is* precise.